Attempt to invoke direct method 'void android.view.SurfaceControl.checkNotReleased()' on a null object reference
Hi I am getting below logs in crashlytics not able to finding the issue what is the issue.is the below logs related to animations .
if yes what is the issue  can any one help me where I did the mistake
crashlytics logs:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'void android.view.SurfaceControl.checkNotReleased()' on a null object reference
       at android.view.SurfaceControl.-$$Nest$mcheckNotReleased()
       at android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction.checkPreconditions(SurfaceControl.java:2941)
       at android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction.hide(SurfaceControl.java:3124)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.syncTransferSplashscreenViewTransaction(ActivityThread.java:4360)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$msyncTransferSplashscreenViewTransaction()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$1.onDraw(ActivityThread.java:4337)
       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1132)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4838)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3775)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2469)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9484)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1405)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1413)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1040)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:930)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1388)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8423)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
        

SplashscreenPlugin.java:
 private void setupSplashScreen(SplashScreen splashScreen) {
        // Setup Splash Screen Delay
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> keepOnScreen);

        // auto hide splash screen when custom delay is defined.
        if (autoHide && delayTime != DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME) {
            Handler splashScreenDelayHandler = new Handler();
            splashScreenDelayHandler.postDelayed(() -> keepOnScreen = false, delayTime);
        }

        // auto hide splash screen with default delay (-1) delay is controlled by the
        // `onPageFinished` message.

        // If auto hide is disabled (false), the hiding of the splash screen must be determined &
        // triggered by the front-end code with the `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` method.

        // Setup the fade
        splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener(new SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSplashScreenExit(@NonNull SplashScreenViewProvider splashScreenViewProvider) {
                View splashScreenView = splashScreenViewProvider.getView();

                splashScreenView
                    .animate()
                    .alpha(0.0f)
                    .setDuration(isFadeEnabled ? fadeDuration : 0)
                    .setStartDelay(isFadeEnabled ? 0 : fadeDuration)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            splashScreenViewProvider.remove();
                        }
                    }).start();
                splashScreenView.clearAnimation();
            }
        });
    }

    private void attemptCloseOnPageFinished() {
        if (autoHide && delayTime == DEFAULT_DELAY_TIME) {
            keepOnScreen = false;
        }
    }

crash is happening but not every time occuring randomly
